# Monty Python's Life of Brian: "Biggus Dickus" translated as "Enormus Vergus"

Tags: traduction, anglais, latin, cinéma

Here is the particular (very funny!) passage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xv2dVNu-Z34&t=136s. And here is some of the dialogue of the French subtitled version.

[image]

One notes that the " Biggus Dickus" name (quite obvious its "latinized" meaning:-)!) was conveyed in French as "Enormus Vergus". From where comes this "latinized" Vergus? Why should be regarded as funny by native French speakers? On the contrary the VF (French dialogues) has *Bitus Grossus* which catches better indeed the original Monty Python spirit. Why the difference between the Vostfr and the VF?

Comment: *Vergus* is a play on [*verge*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/verge#Fran%C3%A7ais) "rod" < Latin *virga* "branch". Wiktionary says the sexual slang is from the 13th century. That gives it the same pedigree as English *member* or about double that of English *prick*. If the mollification over time is also the same, *verge* would be tamer and less funny than *bite*. Hence I'm tempted to think that *bite* is the better translation for *dick*. Maybe *verge* was chosen to blend in with the Latin better. But that's just speculation, since I have no idea how *verge* comes across to a native speaker.

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Mollification* reminds me the first time I saw "soft verge" on an English road sign, and was puzzled... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre lol, I never even thought of the double entendre :D

Comment: [correction: Where does x come from?]

Comment: Literary translation is not like regular translation.  "verge" is very Fanny Hill, if I were translating that into French. [You can't look up the century].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My best bet is that the spoken French dialog has ***Bitus Grossus*** because it better matches the movements of the lips when ***Biggus Dickus*** is pronounced.

The subtitles haven't this constraint and use ***Enormus Vergus*** because :

- it sounds more Latin (*latin de cuisine* precisely)
- is is immediately understood unlike ***Bitus Grossus*** which requires a small effort. (On the other hand, the reversed ***Grossus Bitus*** would have been a good alternative.)

Note that *verge* is not slang but the formal/medical name of it.

Answer (score 4):

*verge* comes across as a bit literary but I think its meaning as *mentula* is widely understood by native speakers.

*Vergus* has indeed a more Latin feel to it than *Bitus*.  The Oxford Latin Dictionary has :

- Vergilius : the name of a Roman *gens*, especially Publius Vergilius Maro (Virgil), the poet, 70 - 19 B.C.
- Vergīnius : the name of a Roman *gens*
- Vērus : a cognomen

*enormus* does not exist in this form in Latin, the correct form of the adjective being *ēnormis*.  One of the translators decided to go full dog Latin, or *latin de cuisine*, as in English and came up with *Bitus Grossus*, the other one wanted to stay closer to actual Latin with *Enormus Vergus*.  I think both translations work equally well.

Comment: Come to think of it, if we're talking about register, not only is *bite* a better match for *dick* but *gros* is also a better match for *big*. Much of the humour of "Biggus Dickus" is how obviously un-Latin it is, using these nice basic English-sounding words. I think the *Enormus Vergus* translator did a good job of making a Latin-like funny name, but missed the point that it's definitely supposed to sound like *latin de cuisine*.

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it.
All foreign movies dubbed in French have different translations for spoken dialogues and subtitles. It's never the same persons doing these translations.
Often, the French subtitles are the same in all French speaking countries but the spoken dialogues are different between French Canadian and French "Parisian".
They've never thought of making something consistent. It's often difficult, for instance, to translate jokes.